# Difference between PocketBook Touch Lux 3 and Tea Touch Lux 3?

Tags: ebook-readers

I'm thinking of getting an ereader, and have an opportunity to buy a PocketBook Touch Lux 3 on sale.

Is there a difference between the PocketBook and the Tea?

Will I have access to software updates if I get the PocketBook?